# Using KCL, KVL and Ohm’s Law find I0 in the circuit in Fig.1.1

Tags: ohms-law, kirchhoffs-laws

I have spent more than 8 hours studying KCL and KVL and Ohm's law but I still can't solve this :[image]

If anyone can help me understand how to find I0, Ix and 2Ix I will really appreciate it.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please show the calculations you have attempted -- knowing where you are making a mistake will help us write more useful answers.

Comment: We don't hand out homework answers here. You need to show us that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself, and **show all of your work**. Then, if you get stuck, as a **specific** question.

Comment: gentlemen i would be happy to show you my practice to finally solve this problem, how can i send pictures of my notebook ? or should i just explain what i did so you can figure out whats wrong.

Comment: @zack__fj You know that \$I_x=2\cdot I_{6k}\$ and therefore that \$I_{4k}=\frac32\,I_x\$. You also know that \$I_o=2\cdot I_{4k}\$ so that means \$I_o=3\cdot I_x\$. So the total in both branches must be \$3\cdot I_x+\frac32\,I_x=\frac92\,I_x\$. But this means that the total is \$\frac{13}2\,I_x\$, counting the dependent current source of \$2\,I_x\$. That must be equal to \$6\:\text{mA}\$. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Use superposition method. https://youtu.be/EX52BuZxpQM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica) to solve this problem. When I was studying this stuff I used the method all the time (without using Mathematica of course).

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image]

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{a}=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_2+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
0=\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_2+\text{I}_4+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_7\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\text{I}_\text{a}+\text{I}_7
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{a}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\text{n}\cdot\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
0=\text{n}\cdot\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_4}+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}+\text{I}_7\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}=\text{I}_\text{a}+\text{I}_7
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Solving for \$\text{I}_1\$, gives:

$$\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{I}_\text{a}\left(\text{R}_2\text{R}_3+\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)+\left(1+\text{n}\right)\text{R}_3\text{R}_4+\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag4$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{Ia == I1 + I5, I5 == n*I2 + I4, I1 == I2 + I3, 
   0 == n*I2 + I4 + I6, I6 == I3 + I7, I2 == Ia + I7, 
   I1 == (V1 - V2)/R1, I2 == V2/R2, I3 == V2/R3, I4 == V1/R4}, {I1, 
   I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, I7, V1, V2}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> (Ia (R2 + R3) R4)/(
   R1 (R2 + R3) + (1 + n) R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)), 
  I2 -> (Ia R3 R4)/(R1 (R2 + R3) + (1 + n) R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)), 
  I3 -> (Ia R2 R4)/(R1 (R2 + R3) + (1 + n) R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)), 
  I4 -> (Ia (R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3)))/(
   R1 (R2 + R3) + (1 + n) R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)), 
  I5 -> Ia - (Ia (R2 + R3) R4)/(
    R1 (R2 + R3) + (1 + n) R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)), 
  I6 -> -((Ia (R1 (R2 + R3) + R3 (R2 + n R4)))/(
    R1 (R2 + R3) + (1 + n) R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4))), 
  I7 -> Ia (-1 + (R3 R4)/(
      R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3) + (R2 + R3 + n R3) R4)), 
  V1 -> (Ia (R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3)) R4)/(
   R1 (R2 + R3) + (1 + n) R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)), 
  V2 -> (Ia R2 R3 R4)/(R1 (R2 + R3) + (1 + n) R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4))}}
```

Using your values, we get:

$$\text{I}_4=\frac{9}{3250}\approx0.00276923\space\text{A}\tag5$$

The code gives the rest of the answers:

```
In[2]:=Clear["Global`*"];
Ia = 6*10^(-3);
n = 2;
R1 = 4*1000;
R2 = 3*1000;
R3 = 6*1000;
R4 = 3*1000;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{Ia == I1 + I5, I5 == n*I2 + I4, I1 == I2 + I3, 
   0 == n*I2 + I4 + I6, I6 == I3 + I7, I2 == Ia + I7, 
   I1 == (V1 - V2)/R1, I2 == V2/R2, I3 == V2/R3, I4 == V1/R4}, {I1, 
   I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, I7, V1, V2}]]

Out[2]={{I1 -> 9/6500, I2 -> 3/3250, I3 -> 3/6500, I4 -> 9/3250, I5 -> 3/650,
   I6 -> -(3/650), I7 -> -(33/6500), V1 -> 108/13, V2 -> 36/13}}

In[3]:=N[%2]

Out[3]={{I1 -> 0.00138462, I2 -> 0.000923077, I3 -> 0.000461538, 
  I4 -> 0.00276923, I5 -> 0.00461538, I6 -> -0.00461538, 
  I7 -> -0.00507692, V1 -> 8.30769, V2 -> 2.76923}}
```